# Stuck on "checking the maximum length of command line arguments..." when running make on MSYS2

Tags: make, msys2, autotools

I am working with an autotools project.
It works on the CI however, when I run it on my work PC it freezes when running make

```
checking for af77... no
checking for xlf90... no
checking for f90... no
checking for pgf90... no
checking for pghpf... no
checking for epcf90... no
checking for gfortran... gfortran
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... yes
checking whether gfortran accepts -g... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments...
```

The workflow I am running locally is located [here](https://github.com/OpenModelica/OMParser.jl/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.yml)

I have also investigated some old resources, and found [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=23999). However, it has been of no use,

The following tools are used:
GCC:

```
    $ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
```

Autoconf:

```
$ autoconf --version
autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.71
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+/Autoconf: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>, <https://gnu.org/licenses/exceptions.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David J. MacKenzie and Akim Demaille.
```

Comment: I believe Windos has a low path length limit, I believe it is 256 characters or so - but I might be wrong on the actual number. MSYS would be affected by that.

Answer (score 2):

My workaround was that I identified with Process Explorer (Former SysInternals tools) the checking sh.exe and killed it.
The compilation (or configure) process continued.

I've read that this is a bug in CMake x.x version and it was corrected, but for me it was with MSYS2 (precisely under "MSYS2 MinGW x64" prompt).